# Section of tautological bundle over $\Bbb C P^1$ with just one zero

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles

I'm asked to provide an example of a section of the tautological bundle over $\Bbb C P^1$ such that it has just a zero. This is a step necessary to prove that the first Chern class is $-1\cdot [\Bbb C P^1]$.

Problem is that I'm unable to provide such section. The obvious candidate would be $[u:v] \mapsto ([u:v],(u/v,1))$ if $v\neq 0$ and $[u:v] \mapsto ([u:v],(1, v/u))$ if $u\neq 0$ but it's not well defined on the overlapping of the two charts of $\Bbb C P^1$.

> I'm not looking for a solution, just some hints

Comment: It is well defined as if $u/v = t \in \Bbb C^*$ your first section is written $(t,1)$ and your second section is $ (1,t^{-1})$ which are equal in $\Bbb CP^1$

Comment: Dear @N.H. mmh, but then the vector $(1,t^{-1})$ and $(t,1)$ would be different, wouldn't they? or am I missing something?

Comment: The points of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ are equivalence classes of $\mathbb{C}$-valued pairs.  What else is in the class containing $[1 :  t^{-1}]$ ?

Comment: Dear @EricTowers, yeah, I know that as points of $\Bbb C P^1$ $[t:1]=[1:t^{-1}]$, but I'm looking for a section of the tautological bundle, therefore I have to associate to each point a vector, and as vectors, $(t,1)$ and $(1,t^{-1})$ are different. If I am misinterpreting your hint, could you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Your candidate doesn't have a zero even if it has been defined somehow. (Of course it doesn't work.) But you can observe why a section with one simple zero exists. After some normalization, one possible candidate (if it were well-defined?) would be $[u:v]\mapsto ([u:v],\sqrt{u^2+v^2}^{-\frac{1}{2}}(u,v))$. Now this expression is invariant under positive scalar multiplication, but multiplying $-1$ makes trouble. But not in craziest way. You see, the vector over $[-u:-v]$ is exactly the negative of the vector over $[u:v]$. Try explain why this phenomenon is related to a section with single zero.

Answer (score 2):

As a hint, it is a fact (that follows from the Chern class, for example) that there is no global holomorphic section. So perhaps you'd like to look for a smooth section that is, say, anti-holomorphic.